# Can you help in App submission status "Invalid Binary" with error "Invalid Swift Support" and "Missing required icon file"?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7.3, swift2

I am getting following error in email, when i submit the binary in iTunes app store with **Application loader** or **XCode**

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "simpleExercise". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> **Invalid Swift Support** - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and
>   resubmit it.
>
> **Missing required icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format .
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

---

For solve **Invalid Swift Support** i made **EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT** flag **YES** and **NO** one by one.
I tried both and submit app to app store but not able to solve the issue.


**AND**


For solve **Missing required icon file** i added app icons files to project bundle.

Please refer below screen shot for all required icons in universal app (iPhone / iPad). 


[image]


As per apple documentation in above image selected image **(Icon-83.5@2x.png)** size is 167 X 167.

Though iTunes team can not get this image and send me a email that **Missing required icon file.**

I am using XCode Version 7.3 (7D175) with Swift 2.2


Can you help me for solve the above both errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After expense many hours / days i am getting my answers my self.

In project **Info.plist** file i have to add particular file **Icon-83.5@2x.png** which size is **167 X 167**.

That's it.

Nothing more.

Please see attached screen shot for more understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For "**Missing required icon file**", you just need to add that icon and I hope you have already done that!

And for the "**Invalid Swift Support**", I had the issues with Application Loader since Xcode 6.4. So, I started uploading the app from the "**Organizer**" (**Xcode > Window > Organizer > Upload to App Store**).

This solves the problem.

Comment: After upload with Organizer **"Invalid Swift Support"** error become solve. But **"Missing required icon file"** error as it is, not solved.

The email form apple is below

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "simpleExercise". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,
The App Store team

Can u help?

Comment: @NilayShah Can I see your Assets?

Comment: same as attached screen shot in question.
Though i am listing again here.
Icon-40.png = 40X40
Icon-40@2x.png = 80X80
Icon-40@3x.png = 120X120
Icon-60@2x.png = 120X120
Icon-60@3x.png = 180X180
Icon-76.png = 76X76
Icon-76@2x.png = 152X152
**Icon-83.5@2x.png = 167X167**
**Icon-167x167.png = 167X167** For error solving only.
Icon-Small.png = 29X29
Icon-Small@2x.png = 58X58
Icon-Small@3x.png = 87X87
Icon-120.png = 120X120
Icon-Small-50.png = 50X50
Icon-Small-50@2x.png = 100X100
iTunesArtwork.png = 512X512
iTunesArtwork@2x.png = 1024X1024

My app is universal (iPhone/IPad)

Any question ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow This

1. Open this web site [MakeAppIcon](https://makeappicon.com/) and add your **1024** Size icon for resize all size as per apple required.
2. Then after enter your mail id and you get all size icon with ASSET FOLDER in your mail. Download the mail.
3. Replace this folder with your current folder.

Comment: @ Hardip, Currently i am using this site size icons for my app. And given folder from MakeAppIcon already exists in the project.

Can you provide me another solution?